# Efficient tiny boolean matrix multiplication

Tags: c, matrix, boolean

I have some unsigned 16 bit integer `s` which I'd like to map to an unsigned 32 bit integer `r` in such a way that each flipped bit in `s` flips at most one (given) bit in `r` -- simply a mapping between `0..16` and `0..32` that is. So we can see this as a matrix equation

```
Ps = r
```

where P is a `32 x 16` boolean matrix, `s` is a `16 x 1` boolean vector and `r` is `32 x 1` boolean vector. I have a gut feeling there exists some super simple hack that I'm missing. Important note: the target machine is a 16 bit mcu!

Here's the best I can do:

```
static u16 P[32] = someArrayOrWhatever();

u32 FsiPermutationHack(u16 s) {
    u32 r;
    for (u16 i = 0; i < 32; i++)
    {
            r |= ((u32)((P[i] & s) > 0) << i);
    }
    return r;
}
```

The rationale is this: the i:th bit of `r` is 1 if and only if `(P[i] & s) != 0x0000`. I am too stupid to disassemble stuff, but I am guessing this would be like ~100 instructions IF we didn't have to do that stupid `u32` cast. But then again, perhaps the compiler auto-splits the loop in two for us in which case it's looking pretty good for us.

Apologies for the tangent, just thought I'd share my attempted solution -- do you have a better one?

Comment: Mathematical description is fine but a bit obscure. Can you give an example?

Comment: As an aside, note that your file-scope array `P` cannot be initialized by a function call as your example seems to show.  In C, function calls may appear only inside function bodies.

Comment: In any case, are you saying that function `FsiPermutationHack()` correctly implements the computation you want, but you're looking for improvements?  In that case, unless you have a specific problem with the code, the question is probably better suited for [Code Review](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/).

Comment: maybe better suited for the code review exchange?

Comment: Oh, and as another aside, you need to initialize variable `r` before you start processing the array.

Comment: The snippet was mostly intended to illustrate the idea but you are of course right about the technicalities.

Comment: And I don't know about Code Review, I'm more looking for Concept Review - maybe the CS stackexchange is better suited but I think that this problem has more to do with the craft of coding rather than the theory. Which makes me think this is the right place for it, after all.

Comment: Coming back to examine the question itself more carefully, I observe that your prose description of the problem does not seem to match your example code.  You are not mapping bits of `s` into bits of `r`.  You are mapping *rows of P* to `r` based on an acceptance predicate encoded in `s`.

Comment: I don't understand what you are trying to say here. I don't think the problem is very unclear at all. You have 16 bits, each of these bits either maps to a number between 0..31, or NULL. The details of the exact mapping is arbitrary. This can be equivalently stated as a binary matrix equation mapping s to r by way of P. What confuses you?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Inasmuch as you say,

> I am guessing this would be like ~100 instructions IF we didn't have
>   to do that stupid u32 cast. But then again, perhaps the compiler
>   auto-splits the loop in two for us in which case it's looking pretty
>   good for us.

and

> I have a gut feeling there exists some super simple hack that I'm missing

, I will interpret you to be asking how to minimize the use of 32-bit arithmetic in this code intended for a 16-bit processor.

You really ought to learn how to disassemble and check the compiled result to see whether the compiler does automatically split the loop as you hypothesize, but supposing that it does not, I don't see why you couldn't do the same manually:

```
static u16 P[32];  /* value assigned elsewhere */

u32 FsiPermutationHack(u16 s) {
    u16 *P_hi = P + 16;
    u16 r_lo = 0;
    u16 r_hi = 0;

    for (u16 i = 0; i < 16; i++) {
        r_lo |= (P[i] & s) != 0) << i;
        r_hi |= (P_hi[i] & s) != 0) << i;
    }

    return ((u32) r_hi << 16) + r_lo;
}
```

That supposes `u16` and `u32` to be unsigned 16-bit and 32-bit (respectively) integers with no padding bits.

Note also that the idea that performing arithmetic with type `u16` instead of `u32` should be an improvement assumes that type `u32` has a higher integer promotion rank than `unsigned int`.  Roughly speaking, that comes down to the implementation's `unsigned int` being a 16-bit type.  That's entirely plausible for an implementation for a 16-bit processor.  On a system whose `int` and `unsigned int` are instead 32-bit types, however, all narrower integer arithmetic arguments would be promoted to 32 bits anyway.

---

**Update:**

As far as the possibility of a better alternative algorithm, I observe that each bit of the result is computed from a different element of array `P`, that the whole value of each element is used, and that the element size is the same as the target machine's native word size.  There seems then no scope for performing fewer 16-bit bitwise AND operations than there are array elements (but see below).

If we accept that each array element must be processed separately, then the provided implementation does a pretty good job of approaching it efficiently:

- It performs only 16-bit computations until the time comes to assemble the final result;
- It computes both the upper and lower halves of the result in the same loop, thus incurring only 16 iterations' worth of loop overhead instead of 32
- It largely removes the extra indexing arithmetic that that would otherwise have required by creating `P_hi` for accessing the upper half of the array

It would be possible to manually unroll the loop to possibly save a few more cycles, but that's the kind of optimization that you absolutely should rely on your compiler to perform for you.

As far as "bit twiddling hacks", the only scope I see for anything of that nature would be processing adjacent pairs of 16-bit array elements as 32-bit unsigned integers.  That would allow performing one 32-bit bitwise AND in place of each two 16-bit ANDs.  That would be coupled with two 32-bit comparisons (*vs.* two 16-bit comparisons in the above code).  The 16-bit shift and bitwise OR operations of the above approach could be retained.  Aside from that having formally undefined behavior as a result of violating the strict aliasing rule, that would involve 32-bit arithmetic, which presumably is about half as fast as 16-bit arithmetic on your 16-bit machine. Performance is better measured than predicted, but I don't see any reason to expect a significant win from that approach.

Comment: I was about to propose to split the matrix in tow submatrices to compute separately the high order u16 word and the low order one from `r` when I realized that it was exactly your solution!

Comment: This was what I was implying with the comment about the compiler splitting it for me as well. Can't accept it as an answer though, because I still suspect there exists some neat bit twiddling hack that fundamentally improves on my solution. An alternative ideal answer would give some rationale as to why my proposed method is unlikely to be improved upon.

Comment: @BenjaminLindqvist, I have added somewhat in the way of an argument for optimality, but if you're not persuaded then I don't know what more I can do.  No one can compare the code presented to an unspecified approach you imagine may exist.  You of course have the alternative of waiting for more answers.  If you wish to do so, then may I suggest that you set some reasonable time limit, after which you accept whichever of the answers you then have that you like best?

Comment: There's nothing wrong with letting a question go unanswered.

Comment: To clarify. I think we've investigated all slight variations on my original solution. But I am not convinced there is no other way of approaching the problem.

Comment: @BenjaminLindqvist, I could believe that there is another, better, approach to the overall task(s) that `FsiPermutationHack()` serves, but inasmuch as you have not disclosed that task, no answer can address it.  As you have couched the problem -- a specific computation to perform based on a specific input format -- I think you are being disingenuous by judging answers based on a completely unsubstantiated assumption that there must be some fundamentally different approach than you have already conceived.

Comment: @BenjaminLindqvist you are right, of course, that you are not obligated to accept any answer, and certainly not mine in particular.  But if indeed you have asked a question to which you are uncertain there exists an answer that will satisfy you, then that question is inappropriate for SO.

Comment: You are pretty off-base and I'd suggest a moderator removes most of this rubbish. Your answer, while lengthy, is simply not all that good, which is why I didn't accept it.

Comment: I didn't notice you had edited, please disregard that last comment. I think your point in that we have to concede traversal of all 32 indices is good and with that in mind, it is hard to shave more off. However, I can see one big possible optimization. Brb